# tnslistener does not currently know of sid given in connect descriptor oracle11g after database successfully created

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've created a database in oracle 11g with the following commands:

```
oradim -NEW -SID TA -STARTMODE auto
sqlplus /as sysdba /nolog @CreateDatabase.sql 
conn / as sysdba
CREATE SPFILE='C:/Databases/Tamiflu/tamifludb.ora' FROM PFILE='C:/Databases/Tamiflu/inittamiflu.ora';
SHUTDOWN 

startup nomount pfile="C:/Databases/Tamiflu/inittamiflu.ora';

CREATE DATABASE db name
   USER SYS IDENTIFIED BY EuroRSCG1
   USER SYSTEM IDENTIFIED BY EuroRSCG1
   LOGFILE GROUP 1 ('C:/Databases/Tamiflu/Logs/redo01.log') SIZE 100M,
           GROUP 2 ('C:/Databases/Tamiflu/Logs/redo02.log') SIZE 100M,
           GROUP 3 ('C:/Databases/Tamiflu/Logs/redo03.log') SIZE 100M
   MAXLOGFILES 5
   MAXLOGMEMBERS 5
   MAXLOGHISTORY 1
   MAXDATAFILES 100
   MAXINSTANCES 1
   CHARACTER SET US7ASCII
   NATIONAL CHARACTER SET AL16UTF16
   DATAFILE 'C:/Databases/Tamiflu/Data/system01.dbf' SIZE 325M REUSE
   EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
   SYSAUX DATAFILE 'C:/Databases/Tamiflu/Data/sysaux01.dbf' SIZE 325M REUSE
   DEFAULT TABLESPACE tbs_1
   DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE tempts1
      TEMPFILE 'C:/Databases/Tamiflu/Data/temp01.dbf' 
      SIZE 20M REUSE
   UNDO TABLESPACE undotbs 
      DATAFILE 'C:/Databases/Tamiflu/Data/undotbs01.dbf'
      SIZE 200M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE UNLIMITED;
```

It successfully executes.

Then when I try to view the DB in SQL Developer, it says it doesn't know the SID.  But I established the SID earlier.

I don't know how to clear oracle's SID cache or. What to do now.

Comment: What's SID entered in SQL Developer? Does it match with the SID of the instance?

Answer (score 0):

A few things don't add up here

- The instance is named ta
- The database init.ora file is named tamiflu
- The create database statement is not correct. what is the database name ? db_name?

All of these values should be consistent.

Comment: I realized much later that Oracle only allows one instance per machine and I was under the assumption that you could have multiple instances.